# how to deploye C# windows form application developed with sql server express 2012 and crystal report

Tags: c#, deployment, crystal-reports, clickonce, sql-server-2012-express

I have developed an application in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. .Net framework 4.5. DBMS i used is sql server 2012 express and for reporting is used Crystal report 13

I want to Create a setup file which can install .net framework, sql server and crystal report on client computer. This setup should be **offline and silent**.

I used click once but it is not working when i choose "Download file same as my application location". I meant offline setup is not working with click once.
Second there is no option to select at which location i need to install software.

I know there is other questions posted same as like this. But i need specific help in above described condition.

Please describe how can i create this type single and standalone setup file for deployment of my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also recently developed an application in C# with Crystal Reports 13 that installs pre-requisites such as .NET Framework 4.5 if needed. I used [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/).

You can also download and use the InstallShield Template. Follow this [article](http://www.brainbrushups.com/2014/02/how-to-create-setup-project-in-visual.html).

**Edit**. For Advanced installer, you will be adding a prerequisite for SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for the appropriate version.

See [this](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=23219).

Comment: Thnx for your advice, but in the link there is no reference of crystal report. Is crystal report installs by setup that you created ?

Comment: Yes, my application installs the Crystal Reports runtime. I used Advanced Installer and added it through the prerequisites.