# Setup and Deployment of windows application along with .net frameworks, crystal reports and windows service

Tags: c#, .net, installation

I am working on windows application I have a new client requirement like everything need to be bundled in single setup file ( example : SQL server 2012 express edition, Application database, Crystal reports, .NET framework,other 2 applications and Windows Service)

I did setup file along with Database using installer class following the below site  (http://www.rajneeshverma.com/post/2012/08/16/Setup-and-Deployment-of-Windows-Application-with-SQL-Server-Database-using-Visual-Studio-2010.aspx). Its working fine

And I tried for crystal report added some merge modules but I don't know which merge module need to add exactly so I added all modules

So, how can I add .NET Framework, Windows Service, Crystal Reports, SQL Server 2012 express edition to a single setup file? Can you please show me a way to chase this task

Thanks & Regards,
Sridhar.

Comment: Sounds like you better get some serious installer program. Like `Inno`. It also sounds to me that you use old Chrystal. I think they now have server. So, you need to pack all these things into installer and make installer install them silently. Prepare your batch command files, for your win service for example, and make installer run them

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this answer [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507183/how-to-deploye-c-sharp-windows-form-application-developed-with-sql-server-expres/24520709#24520709). I think Advanced Installer has what you are looking for. You can be able to bundle your pre-requisites quite easily with it including setups for Crystal Reports runtime and SQL Express.

Example below.

[image]

You will be able to put everything into a single setup file.